# How to protect visible email address from spam with gem for Ruby 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email-spam

I'd like to obfuscate an email address on my webpage. I'm hoping to avoid JS in case my users deactivate it.

I found this gem: [actionview-encoded_mail_to](https://github.com/reed/actionview-encoded_mail_to) but it doesn't seem to work for me. It shows the full email address on the page (which is good), but it also shows it in the console.

I tried the 3 examples with the same result. The gem appears in my Gemfile so should be correctly installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can always roll your own but, first, that gem definitely works. Here's what I did...

#### Using the Gem

I added the gem to a Rails 4.2 app:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'actionview-encoded_mail_to'
```

I installed it:

```
$ bundle install
```

I entered the console:

```
$ rails console
```

I made the helper methods available in the console:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
```

Called the `mail_to` helper with the same arguments as the example:

```
mail_to "me@domain.com", nil, replace_at: "_at_", replace_dot: "_dot_", class: "email"
```

...and got this result:

```
"<a class=\"email\" href=\"mailto:me@domain.com\">me_at_domain_dot_com</a>"
```

That `"me_at_domain_dot_com"` looks properly obfuscated. What steps did you take?

#### Rolling your own obfuscation

It would be a trivial string substitution to obfuscate an email string, we can just use `sub`:

```
def obfuscate_email(email, replace_at: '_at_', replace_dot: '_dot_')
  email.sub("@", replace_at).sub ".", replace_dot
end
```

I tested that out in the console:

```
obfuscate_email "me@example.com"
# => "me_at_example_dot_com"
```

You can place that method in `application_helper.rb` and use it in any of your views:

```
link_to obfuscate_email(user.email), "mailto:#{user.email}"
# => "<a href=\"mailto:me@example.com\">me_at_example_dot_com</a>"
```

*Note that the href must be the unobfuscated email in order for it to work properly.*

#### Towards a more complete `mail_to` helper

```
def obfuscated_mail_to(email, options = {})
  link_to obfuscate_email(email), "mail_to:#{email}", options
end
```

Testing that in the console:

```
obfuscated_mail_to "me@example.com", class: "email"
=> "<a class=\"email\" href=\"mail_to:me@example.com\">me_at_example_dot_com</a>"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: (This is in reference to the gem, not your answer)  the mail_to isn't obfuscated, when using that gem, which to me makes it basically useless? i mean you are trying to prevent automated scraping, so unless you don't include the mail_to, or change it,  even a simple bot can pull the page, yank all the mail_to and have access to the email address.  All it appears to do is make harder for the end user to cut/paste it. Now if it didn't have the mailto: link it would be somewhat more obfuscated...

Comment: That's right, the `href` of the link tag isn't obfuscated because then it wouldn't work. It would open your mail client and add the obfuscated email to the `to:` field of the email, so you'd have to deobfuscate it before sending the email. You have to make a decision, do you want a functioning `mail_to` or do you want to completely obfuscate the email and strip it of its default functionality? In the latter case just place the obfuscated email as a plain string on your page: `My email: <%= obfuscate_email user.email %>`

Comment: Ok, both your answers make sense. I did hope that the href email would be obfuscated since that seems to be the only way a scrapper wouldn't get it, and I did wonder how obfuscating it would allow to send the email. Tx!